# Extract specific value from object array in Oracle 12c

Tags: arrays, json, regex, oracle, serialization

I am by no means a developer but I have some skills to cobble together scripts and make them work. But the following seems way out of my ballpark.

I have to deal with the following content inside a VARCHAR2 field in Oracle 12c:

```
{
"channel": "Email",
"events": [
    {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "reportId",
                "type": "number",
                "value": "87654321"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "subjectLine",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "Bla bla subject line"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "messageName",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "bla bla message name"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "docType",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "html"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "eventId",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "kTZA01zahw=="
            }
        ],
        "code": "emailOptOut",
        "namespace": null,
        "timestamp": "2018-01-25T09:21:48.085Z",
        "version": null
    }
],
"identifiers": [
    {
        "isOriginal": true,
        "name": "ENCODED_RECIPIENT_ID",
        "value": "Njc5MjM1MS1"
    },
    {
        "isOriginal": true,
        "name": "Email",
        "value": "foo@bar.com"
    }
],
"provider": "Provider",
"source": "Source",
"version": "1",
"Id": "aa-bb-cc-dd"}
```

I initially believed this to be JSON but I am thinking this could just be the serialized representation of an object.

Anyhow, I need to extract the value of the email address (`"value": "foo@bar.com"`) stored inside the identifiers array where the name equals `"name": "Email"`.

I have tried parsing this using `json_value` and `json_query`, but failed because I was not able to extract the value where the key was `Email`. Also, the desired value is not always stored at the same index position so I cannot target it that way either.

Then I moved on to trying it with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` but after a lot of searching on StackOverflow and Google I could not find any regular expression that would help me do this. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no knowledge of regexps so I had to copy and paste and try and also failed there.

Note: ideally, I would be able to run this inside an SQL statement, like a view, because I need to use that parsed data as a starting point for something else.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the match_parameter `'n'`  of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` which allows the period (.), which is the `match-any-character` character, to match the `newline` character.

`\s*` - match 0 or more spaces

`.+` - matches 1 or more characters, so

(.`+@.+.com)` -  matches email id of the form `<foo>@<bar.com>`.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
          col1,
          '"identifiers":.+"name"\s*:\s*"Email".+"value"\s*:\s*"(.+@.+.com)"',
          1,
          1,
          'n',
          1)
  FROM yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f19b/12)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. But I just realized that there seems to occur a special case where this does not extract the desired value. I will look into this.

Question about the email address: the top level domain does not need to be .com, or is it?

Comment: @CBennett : I gave you a general idea. You may have to modify the REGEXP to suit your needs and to generalize for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

if it isn't too late use something like

```
select jt.*
from (
select '{
"channel": "Email",
"events": [
    {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "reportId",
                "type": "number",
                "value": "87654321"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "subjectLine",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "Bla bla subject line"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "messageName",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "bla bla message name"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "docType",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "html"
            },
            {
                "isSync": false,
                "name": "eventId",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "kTZA01zahw=="
            }
        ],
        "code": "emailOptOut",
        "namespace": null,
        "timestamp": "2018-01-25T09:21:48.085Z",
        "version": null
    }
],
"identifiers": [
    {
        "isOriginal": true,
        "name": "ENCODED_RECIPIENT_ID",
        "value": "Njc5MjM1MS1"
    },
    {
        "isOriginal": true, 
        "name": "Email",
        "value": "foo@bar.com"
    }
],
"provider": "Provider",
"source": "Source",
"version": "1",
"Id": "aa-bb-cc-dd"}' js 
from dual)d,
json_table(d.js, '$.identifiers[*]' columns(name varchar2(20) path '$.name', value varchar2(20) path '$.value' ))jt
where name = 'Email'
```